# NSURLConnection and JSON Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, nsurlconnection

I am stuck with something crazy. I used `ASIHTTPRequest` to receive my data from a web service and everything worked fine. I switched to using a `NSURLConnection` and I am receiving the same data and parsing it the same way but my code won't recognize the data with the `NSURLConnection`.

Here is the data I am receiving (from `NSLog`)

```
Did receive data: {"d":"[{\"id\":1.0,\"Category\":1,\"hPlan\":0.0,\"Tip\":\"It takes 3500   
calories to gain a pound. If you want to lose a pound per week, reduce your calorie
intake by 250 calories and incorporate daily physical activity that will burn 250   
calories.\",\"TipDate\":\"2012-05-12T00:00:00\",\"TimeStamp\":\"AAAAAAAAB9I=\"}]"}


2012-06-06 09:42:11.809 StaticTable[27488:f803] Jsson Array: 0  
2012-06-06 09:42:11.809 StaticTable[27488:f803] Jsson Array: (null)
```

Code:

```
#import "UYLFirstViewController.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h" 
#import "JSON.h"

@interface UYLFirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation UYLFirstViewController

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark === UIViewController ===
#pragma mark -

@synthesize MessageField;
@synthesize jsonArray = _jsonArray;
@synthesize TipLabelField;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Tickle!", @"Tickle!");
     self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"heart_plus"];

    [self GetTipOfDay];

}
return self;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
-(BOOL)GetTipOfDay{

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EEEE MMMM d, YYYY"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];


NSString *yourOriginalString = @"Tip of the Day for ";

yourOriginalString = [yourOriginalString stringByAppendingString:dateString];
TipLabelField.text = yourOriginalString;


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/api/GetHealth.asmx/getTipOfDay"];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];



// Clear text field
MessageField.text = @"";

// Start hud
  MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
  hud.labelText = @"Gathering Tip of the Day...";

return TRUE;

}

- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

[MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];


NSLog(@"Did receive data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);


NSDictionary *responseDict = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] JSONValue];

NSString *jsonResponse = [responseDict objectForKey:@"d"];

self.jsonArray = [jsonResponse JSONValue];


NSLog(@"Jsson Array: %d", [jsonArray count]);
NSLog(@"Jsson Array: %@", jsonArray);


NSEnumerator *myEnumerator;
myEnumerator = [jsonArray objectEnumerator];
int i;
i=0;
id myObject;

while (myObject = [myEnumerator nextObject])
{
    NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[self.jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"Checking for games");

    NSString *myCheck = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"FName"];

    if ([myCheck length] != 0)
    {
        // NSLog(myCheck);
        MessageField.text = myCheck;
    }
}

} 



- (void)viewDidUnload {
[self setMessageField:nil];
[self setTipLabelField:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
}
@end


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UYLFirstViewController : UIViewController{
  NSMutableArray *jsonArray;  
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *MessageField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *jsonArray;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TipLabelField;

-(BOOL)GetTipOfDay;


@end
```

Comment: Can you post complete code of your file so we can have a better look at what is going on?

Comment: @Ed F  I don't see in your code any of the delegate methods needed to implement NSURLConnection correctly :)

Comment: I have added the complete files

Comment: Why are you converting away from ASI? They are no longer supporting it, it doesn't mean that it doesn't work.

Comment: I went back to AIS and I am still getting the error.  it does not seem to be anything with the retrieving of data becuase i am getting the complete JSON back.  it seems to be with moving the JSON into the array.  array is always empty.  I did change the app to ARC.  could this be an issue?

Answer (score 3):

`-didRecieveData` can be called multiple times as the bytes and chunks come in. You should move your logic to `-connectionDidFinishLoading`. This will let you know when the connection is completely done and the data is ready to be parsed.

Answer (score 3):

You're only implementing one of the NSURLConnectionDelegate methods. Try adding this

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    //set up *receivedMutableString as instance variable in .h
    if (!receivedMutableString) {
        self.receivedMutableString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    } else {
        NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [receivedMutableString appendString:dataString];
    }
}


- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    //Now receivedMutableString contains all json data
    ...continue with your code 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSURLConnection` is a bit of overkill if you're just doing a simple `GET` request (and you're developing for an iOS version that supports blocks). You can do this in a `dispatch_async` block:

```
- (void) getData 
{
    dispatch_async(<some_queue>, ^{ 

        NSError  * error = nil;
        NSString * response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: stringWithContentsOfURL: requestUrl error: &error];

        // process JSON

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // Update UI on main thread

        }

    });
}
```

As you can see from my example code, you can also perform your JSON processing on the background queue (provided the method you're calling is thread safe). Just pass back to the main queue to update the UI.

Comment: Is seems like even when i do this my JSON string is not being put into an array.  the array is always empty.

Comment: It sounds as though your JSON string isn't valid. Try pasting it into http://jsonlint.com/ to check it is.

Comment: I went to the site and entered it and got 'valid JSON' for the result.  This is driving me nuts...    {"d":"[{\"id\":1.0,\"Category\":1,\"hPlan\":0.0,\"Tip\":\"It takes 3500 calories to gain a pound. If you want to lose a pound per week, reduce your calorie intake by 250 calories and incorporate daily physical activity that will burn 250 calories.\",\"TipDate\":\"2012-05-12T00:00:00\",\"TimeStamp\":\"AAAAAAAAB9I=\"}]"}

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue had nothing to do with fetching from the webservice.  I had to define my array as __strong.  Thanks for all the help.  I did get some good ideas on how to do things better.